# Nil when unwrapping viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey) (Swift)

Tags: swift, uiview

I am trying to do a custom transition animation. I have create an animation object that conforms to `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    let duration = 1.0

    func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {
        return duration
    }

    func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        let fromView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey)!

        //Animate out
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: { () -> Void in
            fromView.frame.origin.x -= 200
            }) { (Bool) -> Void in
                transitionContext.completeTransition(true)

        }

    }

}
```

I am getting an error when trying to set the frame of `fromView`. It crashes on trying to force unwrap nil. What am I doing wrong here? Why is my fromView nil?

Comment: Error goes here        
let fromView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey)!

Comment: @Md.MuzahidulIslam yes. Do you know why it has an error here?

Comment: Because your are trying to forcefully unwrap the nil value. Write this line like that if let fromView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey){
}else{
// handle nil value
}

Comment: Yeah. I mean why is the value nil? There should be a view at UITransitionContextFromViewKey. It works for UITransitionContextToViewKey but not UITransitionContextFromViewKey.

Answer (score 23):

Found the answer to this if anyone else is having this issue. I had `myViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Custom`. For some reason this seems to be a bug and causes it to crash. Also the fromView controller isn't properly removed from the container view when `transitionContext.completeTransition(true)` is set. Just remove the custom presentation style line and it will work.

Comment: This is actually a swift bug.  If you translate the code to ObjC, it works even using the .Custom presentation style. :-(

Comment: I experience this behavior on iOS 9 even with the code written in ObjC.

Comment: good (enough) work around is `let fromView = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from)!.view!` as sometimes you need to set the `modalPresentationStyle` like for showing a view over the current context

Comment: @SuperDuperTango This bug is still present with iOS 12.

Comment: it is efing unfortunate that i keep hitting this problem again and again after long enough time that i forget the solution. but you know you are there once you see own upvote. thanks again for this little gem because apple docs explicitly state that you should set the custom

Comment: the big caveat with this approach is that it will disable any overriding of `presentationController(forPresented:presenting:source:)`.

Answer (score 14):

This is the expected behavior:

> If NO is returned from -shouldRemovePresentersView, the view
>   associated with UITransitionContextFromViewKey is nil during
>   presentation.  This intended to be a hint that your animator should
>   NOT be manipulating the presenting view controller's view.  For a
>   dismissal, the -presentedView is returned.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CustomTransitions/Listings/CustomTransitions_Custom_Presentation_AAPLCustomPresentationController_m.html